# How do I correctly handle Back button in MAUI MauiAppCompatActivity with OnBackPressed deprecated?

Tags: c#, android, .net, maui

So MAUI Android `MainActivity` is inherits `MauiAppCompatActivity`, which marks `OnBackPressed` obsolete. Apparently I need to handle two different flows depend on the OS version?

```cs
    protected override async void OnCreate(Bundle? savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (OperatingSystem.IsAndroidVersionAtLeast(33))
        {
            OnBackInvokedDispatcher.RegisterOnBackInvokedCallback(0, this);
        }
    }

    public override void OnBackPressed()
    {
        // Only when Android < 33
        if (!OperatingSystem.IsAndroidVersionAtLeast(33))
        {
            if (!HandledBackPressed())
            {
                base.OnBackPressed(); // Warning here
            }
        }
    }

    // Similar code for handling with Android 33+ with no issue
```

However since `OnBackPressed` is marked as `Obsolete`, I still receive a warning. How do I handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to deal with the Back Button on Android screen, you can override method `OnBackButtonPressed` on `AppShell.xaml.cs`

```
 public partial class AppShell : Shell
    {
        public AppShell()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }   
        // This also works for overriding Android on-screen back button
        protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
        {

            bool flag;

#if ANDROID
            flag = MauiGetContactsApp.Platforms.Android.DeviceService.IsDeviceVersionBiggerThanR();
#elif IOS
             
#endif

            // true or false to disable or enable the action
            return base.OnBackButtonPressed();
        }
    }
```

Here, we can get the Android version by [invoking native code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/invoke-platform-code?view=net-maui-8.0) .

You can refer to the following code:

```
namespace MauiGetContactsApp.Platforms.Android
{
    public static class DeviceService
    {
        public static bool IsDeviceVersionBiggerThanR() {

            if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.R) {
                 return true;
            }else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Update:**

In Maui blazor, you can override method `DispatchKeyEvent`.

Please refer to the following code:

```
public override bool DispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e)
{
    if ((e.KeyCode == Keycode.Back) && (e.Action == KeyEventActions.Down))
    {

         bool flag =  OperatingSystem.IsAndroidVersionAtLeast(33);

        if (flag) // this will cancel the back button pressed event
            return true;

    }
    return base.DispatchKeyEvent(e);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am sorry I forgot to mention it's MAUI Hybrid (Blazor). In MAUI Hybrid, I assume the equivalent is `MainPage.xaml`, however the `OnBackButtonPressed` is not invoked there when I tried. Also MAUI Blazor has a default behavior that go backwards in history which I want to override as well.

Comment: Please check my updated answer. :)

Comment: Oh I see, so ignore the Back button event altogether and just override the `DispatchKeyEvent`. Thanks, this works.

Comment: Congrats. Happy coding... :)